# False CloudFormation Drift Detection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have AWS Config setup so that it has a rule that detects CloudFormation drift. But there are some cloudformation templates that are flagged as drifted by Config but when I navigate to that template in the CloudFormation Dashboard, “detect drift” and “view drift results”, the drift status is “IN_SYNC.” Has someone encountered this issue?

Comment: Drift detection is [not perfect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html#drift-considerations). Maybe this is what  you are experiencing?

Comment: I will take a look at the documentation you provided. Thanks!